# How to add the user name in drupal views path?

Tags: drupal, path, drupal-views

I created a view to dispalay a page with all my articles but I can not make it to dispaly the user name in the path - mysite.com/articles/username with a normal menu entry in the main menu.
In the navigation the blog module created a My Blog link with the path mysite.com/blogs/username.My blog is not in the views list.

How can I creat a link My Articles with path similar to My Blog?

Answer (score 0):

In your View that outputs the articles have you tried clicking on Advanceds > Relationships and adding "Content: Author". You might be able to do something with the path then.

Alternatively, you should have Pathauto installed. If not, install it and go here: /admin/config/search/path/patterns then populate the article field to include the author name (something like [node:author]).